# Shall I use Let & to avoid Var ~ [JavaScript - ES6 - Uses Of Var]?

Tags: javascript

I knew that we should use Let in case the variable we need to create will be reassigned another values but what is different from use var as below will resulted to same output & result:

```
let price;
console.log(price);    // Output: undefined

var result;
console.log(result)    // Output: undefined
```

**Finally**, Shall we always use Let & to avoid using var forever especially after ES6 updates or is there any use for Var that we should stick to ?

Comment: `let` is block-scoped, `var` is function-scoped.

Comment: We avoid opinion-based answers about what you *should* use.

Comment: The only sensible use case left for `var`s are global variables which might be (accidentally or intentionally) declared multiple times.